# Related to bounds for n-th prime

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) we have the bounds:

$$\log n+ \log \log n - 1 < \dfrac {p_n}{n} < \log n+ \log \log n $$, for $n \geq 6$.

Can this constant $1$ be improved in the following way:

> For every $1>c>0$ there exists $n(c)$ so that we have
>
> $$\log n+ \log \log n - c < \dfrac {p_n}{n} < \log n+ \log \log n $$, for $n \geq n(c)$.

Of course $c \in \mathbb R$ and $n(c) \in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 1):

The same article as you link says
$$\frac{p_n}{n}=\log n+\log\log n-1+o(1).$$
Therefore, for any $c>0$ and large enough $n$,
$$\log n+\log\log n-1<\frac{p_n}{n}<\log n+\log\log n-1+c.$$